# Web-scraping dynamic website with user input using Selenium and Python

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, xpath, iframe, css-selectors

As A Swimmer, I am trying to pull times from a table that can be accessed after the User Inputs their name or other optional fields. The website dynamically generates this data. Below is my current code which does not factor in user inputs.

I am very confused about how selenium's automation works and how to find the right text field for it to read my results and for the rest of my code to extract the table.

Can anyone give some advice on how to proceed?

Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance.

This Is My Current Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
site = 'https://www.swimming.org.nz/results.html'
wd = webdriver.Chrome( "C:\\Users\\joseph\\webscrape\\chromedriver.exe")
wd.get(site)
html = wd.page_source
df = pd.read_html(html)
df[1].to_csv('Results.csv')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start with you need to send a *character sequence* to the ***Swimmer*** field.

To send a character sequence to the ***Swimmer*** field as the elements are within an [***iframe***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe/53276478#53276478) so you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52603847/how-to-sleep-webdriver-in-python-for-milliseconds/52607451#52607451) for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  - Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

    ```
    driver.get("https://www.swimming.org.nz/results.html")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe#iframe")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[id^='x-MS_FIELD_MEMBER']"))).send_keys("Joseph Zhang")
    ```
  - Using *XPATH*:

    ```
    driver.get("https://www.swimming.org.nz/results.html")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@id='iframe']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[starts-with(@id, 'x-MS_FIELD_MEMBER')]"))).send_keys("Joseph Zhang")
    ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: swim]

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Switch to an iframe through Selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python/44847390#44847390)
- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315587/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-una/50315715#50315715)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441658/selenium-in-python-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-unable-to/53442511#53442511)